# Android: Insmod disagrees about version of symbol module_layout

Tags: android, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am attempting to use NFS on my Xiaomi Redmi Note 9S, it uses a custom ROM called Resurrection Remix OS. I am replacing my old kernel with a newly compiled one, with NFS built-in.

I am using the kernel source found [here](https://github.com/MiCode/Xiaomi_Kernel_OpenSource/tree/curtana-q-oss), the official kernel for the phone made by Xiaomi. I couldn't find the exact kernel source for my custom ROM, but the phone boots regardless.

At first, I only compiled the modules for NFS, however using `insmod` on `sunrpc.ko` requires `__audit_inode_child`, so a new kernel with `CONFIG_AUDIT_SYSCALL=y` is necessary. I also decided to make all the NFS modules built-in.

I made the changes to my `.config`, and compiled the entire kernel
(besides the device tree: `CONFIG_BUILD_ARM64_DT_OVERLAY=n` because of compilation errors).

With the new kernel from `arch/arm64/boot/Image`, I unpacked the `boot.img` from my device and swapped out the kernels and it boots, with NFS support listed in `/proc/filesystems`.

However, now none of the modules from `/vendor/lib/modules` work. Which is to be expected, they weren't built against this new kernel's source.

Trying to remedy this issue by inserting the newly compiled modules with `insmod` say `disagrees about version of symbol module_layout`.

How is this possible? These modules were compiled alongside the running kernel (same source code)

Comment: Are you sure that it tries actually **new** module and not the old one?

Answer (score 0):

Something must have went wrong when creating the boot image, most likely the wrong kernel was copied (I have multiple kernel sources downloaded and compiled).

I repacked boot.img with a newly compiled kernel image and no module loading needed, every module in `/vendor/lib/modules` was loaded on boot.